# Jade Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ide, editor, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting, pug

I wonder if there is an option I missed in Visual Studio 2013 to get the *[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)* syntax highlighting to work?

There is a pretty good integration of *Node.js*, *Express* and *Jade* in Visual Studio 2013, but it seems it lacks a proper syntax highlighting.
In that [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) Tool of Microsoft the *Jade* syntax works pretty well and I dont't get because of what that features is missing in VS 2013. Maybe I made a mistake at some point of installation, project creating, missed an option or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new [NTVS beta version](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/releases/view/104141) I found this today and it works great:

```
NTVS supports the following:

...  
Jade syntax highlighting -- New for Beta  
...
```

For a download and more information see the Node.js Tools for Visual Studio project site on [CodePlex](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I looked into it a couple of months ago and didn't find any resources for handling Jade better in Visual Studio at the time and there may not currently be any solution short of writing the tools you need yourself.

With that said, I did ask one of the developers behind a popular build extension for using languages like LESS or CoffeeScript in Visual Studio if he's considered adding Jade support and his answer was that they're working on it. I unfortunately have no idea what the timeline would be.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you, I'm hoping for a solution as well. In the meantime I found a combination of Visual Studio, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) and [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) works well enough for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So after I haven't found something and nobody said something different for about 2 weeks, I'm aware of not missed something at the installation, a setting or something else.

I will still keep eyes open and update here if I find a way.