# Can I write Jade in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, pug

It seems that I cannot natively write Jade in Visual Studio 2013, but is there a plugin that will recognize the syntax and compile to HTMl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jade Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553974/jade-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, all info and download links are here:

https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/

**update** - have a look here, you might find your answer here:
http://loldemar.azurewebsites.net/vs2013-and-jade/

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, Visual Studio still doesn't recognize Jade markup with that plugin.

Comment: Yes, I use that for writing/compiling LESS...it appears to support Markdown, but even with that plugin/extension, .jade files aren't recognized.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most legit solution out there!